# routing with netplan

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, wifi, routing, netplan

I have a problem configuring two network interfaces on an Ubuntu server version **18.04**. I have an Ethernet network interface, configured via netplan with a static IP address, which I would like to manage all local traffic (**192.168.1.0/24**). Then I have a wifi network interface (usb) to which I would like to direct all external traffic (in my testing environment, wifi and ethernet have the same subnet, which will then be different in the place where I am going to install).

At the moment I have tried both configuring netplan and iptables, but I still haven't been able to get it to work. To test I use the `ping` command to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and monitor the traffic on the network interface with the command: `sudo tcpdump -i <interface name> icmp`.

when I execute the `ping www.google.com` command, I see the traffic passing through the **eno1** interface, while if I specify the network interface to use at the ping command it works well. I would like the traffic to be automatically redirected to the wifi interface when the traffic is external to the network.

How can I do to achieve this result? At the moment the wifi dynamically gets an ip after I connect it via the command: `sudo nmcli d wifi connect <SSID> password <WIFI PASSWORD>`